# Any way to clear and reload scripts in a page without affecting user experience?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to clear and reload my scripts in my application using a setTimeout(), without refreshing the page or doing anything that may affect user experience. Is this possible?

Note: I am using my scripts to insert html and css code so the my html must also reload in a way or else my scripts will keep reloading more and more elements in the page.

Comment: Are these all scripts you have written, or are you referring to libraries and such you have linked?

Comment: scripts that I have written

Comment: can you place a certain class on all the elements you add so they can be stripped?

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around this - Are you REALLY trying to refresh the page, but you just don't want to download everything again?

Comment: well I really don't mind downloading everything again as long as it doesnt affect user experience. It's a long story but this is the issue: I have a slideshow, I'm making an api request to get the pictures for this slideshow, then another script is getting all the data from the request and putting it into a nice animated slideshow by inserting a bunch of elements per picture in the html. The reason I want to reload the scripts is to make another api request every 5 minutes in case there are new pictures, and to put these new pictures correctly in the slideshow

Comment: the placing a class on all my elements to be stripped sounds like a nice work-around to clearing the html before reloading. Let me try to implement it

Comment: Okay, it doesn't sound like what your looking for is to reload the scripts at all.  You want to reset the slider and just call your existing script again.  You might want to start some new question, giving us information about your slider and how you set it up, and we can probably help you with that.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I actually have a program with an image gallery in it.  What I do is wrap each image in a control (you can use a div) with a unique attribute (you could use image URL) and then if there are new images, add them, and remove any that are no longer returned.  That would probably give your users the best experience.

Comment: Maybe. But I managed it to work in this way by doing what you suggested.  I added a class to the html elements that needed to be cleared before re-executing the functions in my other scripts. Then in the solution that you posted below I added $('.stripHTML').remove(); before the execution of the functions. This gets the job done: it clears the html elements if there are any, it makes the api request, and it puts the new data in the slideshow every x seconds.

Comment: Well, if it works, and you are happy then so am I!

Comment: the control wrap that counts the images and only adds those that are new is probably the best idea as you say. I had thought about it when I started solving this issue. But given the complexity of one of my scripts (particularly the one that pushes all the data into the html and animates the slideshow), it was a little difficult to implement.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place everything you want to reload (functions, variables, objects, etc) within an object, and then call them using YourObject.FunctionName(); Then, you just reload the script as you see fit by adding a new script tag to the header (function provided in code sample), with a timestamp to prevent caching.

**somefile.js**

```
YourObject = function()
{
   self = this;
   this.myvar1 = 1234;
   this.yourvar2 = 1234;
   this.reloadSeconds = 90;
   this.FunctionName = function(){
     //Do something Here
   };
   this.FunctionName2 = function(){
     //Do something Else Here
   };
   this.reloadMe = function(){
     var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
     var script= document.createElement('script');
     script.src= '/path_to/somefile.js?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime();
     head.appendChild(script);
  };
  setTimeout(function(){self.reloadMe()},self.reloadSeconds*1000);
}
```

There are quite a few different syntax options for this, you'll have to find the one that is closest to your current code and go with that.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that it will not clear the previous stuff loaded, so all my functions,variables,objects are being loaded on top of each other. This in turn damages the user experience since my scripts are injecting html and css code over and over again

Comment: As they are part of this object, they will all be overwritten.  If you make any instances, you will want to make sure they are themselves contained in the object so they too will be overwritten.  Do you have anything specific you think will not?

Comment: Oh I see. So the functions I am calling in the object should not have been created in other scripts?

Comment: right now i'm doing something like this:    reloadScripts = function()
{
   self = this;
   this.reloadSeconds = 10;
   this.myfunction1(); //created in x script
   this.myfunction2(); //created in y script

   this.reloadMe = function(){
     var head= document.getEl ........

Comment: correct, you move all of your code into objects, and then reload the file containing those (or that) object(s)

Comment: I did what you told me but it's still loading elements on top of each other in the webapp. The thing is that my js code is inserting elements into my html code so if the html isnt being cleared it will just keep creating more and more elements in the page

Comment: for others, please see conversation between trex005 and I in the comments of the main question. There are some very minor changes to this solution. Also, there is no need to place all the code in the object. It's ok to have the code in other scripts and just call the main function wrappers from the other scripts from the object. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nope it is not possible without some kind of a hack... i would not recommend doing such things. But you can try something like this:

```
$('script').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') !== 'assets/js/jquery.js') {
        var source_old = $(this).attr('src');

        // remove source
        $(this).attr('src', '');

        // set source again and avoid caching
        setTimeout(function(){ $(this).attr('src', source_old + '?'+new Date()); }, 250);
    }
});
```

This will reload all scripts on your page except Jquery.

Comment: If this was working, would the effect of the clearing/reloading be visible in the debugger in any way? Using Google Chrome

Comment: in html source you should see new script src.